# Reading text file and skipping blank lines until EOF is reached

Tags: java, bufferedreader, runtimeexception, blank-line

I am trying to read csv file full of text; however if there is a blank line in the middle somewhere, the whole thing breaks and I get a:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

How would I go about removing/ignoring blank lines as long as it's not the end of the file?

```
        file = new FileReader(fileName);
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                     //do lots of stuff to sort the data into lists etc
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("INPUT DATA WAS NOT FOUND, PLEASE PLACE FILE HERE: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (file != null) {
            try {
                file.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Ignore issues during closing
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's this part that's causing problems:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

      //do lots of stuff to sort the data into lists etc
      // **** Something assumes line is not empty *******
    }
```

To ignore blank lines, add this check to make sure the line has something:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.length() > 0) {
      //do lots of stuff to sort the data into lists etc
    }           
}
```

Comment: Actually you should do `if(line.trim().length() > 0)` to catch empty lines that may have white space.

Comment: Cheers, that was a very simple fix!

Comment: @Jared Depends on how you define 'blank'.  If 'blank' lines have non-terminating whitespace characters, then yes, you'll want to apply `trim()`.  If blank lines just have line-termination characters, `reader.readLine()` will return an empty string.

Comment: @lreeder this isn't going to be a problem if you are only reading in computer generated files (which are unlikely to add in unneeded white space).  But it _is_ something you should be wary of when reading in manually generated input (where users may accidentally or unknowingly input unneeded white space).